# Remove a JMS message from MQ Queue using JMSMessageID

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, mq

Is there a way to remove a JMS message from an IBM MQ Queue using JMSMessageId ina Java application(not using tools)? Also are such operations vendor-specific?

Looked through the API for receive operations which are used to remove messages, but for removing specific messages, do we need to filter using MessageSelector and remove appropriately, or is there a more simple way? [checking for any available method which can be directly used]

Can you please provide tutorials/examples [can be links too] to show the API usage for such operations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `JMSMessageID` as the only message property in a selector, WMQ optimizes the lookup to be the same as a native WMQ API get by `MQMD.MessageID` which is an indexed field in the queue.  Please see the [JMS Message Selection](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/jm25420_.htm) topic for more details.

```
QueueReceiver rcvr = sess.createReceiver(inputQ, "JMSCorrelationID = '"+msgId+"'")
```

You can also do the same thing using native WMQ API calls using Java native code.  You would do a normal `GET` operation but specify the message ID in the `MQMD` structure.

```
myMsg.messageId = someMsgID; 
MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions(); 
myQueue.get(myMsg, gmo);
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. Edited question. I meant it to be simple(in a propgrammer's view).

Comment: I've never met a simple programmer.  ;-)

Comment: :) Got it wrong again! Simple Code - Readable, To the Point, reusing available utilities/API.

Answer (score 0):

**How to delete specific message form queue by using messageid?**

I also have like your problem, I provide the resuable function. You just need to pass `MessageId` and `Queue` name. It is ok for me.

```
private void deleteMessage(String messageId, String queueName) {
    try {
         JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi");
         JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
         MBeanServerConnection conn = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
         ObjectName name = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost");
         BrokerViewMBean proxy = (BrokerViewMBean)MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(conn, name, BrokerViewMBean.class, true);
         for (ObjectName queue : proxy.getQueues()) {  
            QueueViewMBean queueBean = (QueueViewMBean) MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(conn, queue, QueueViewMBean.class, true);
            if(queueBean.getName().equals(queueName)) {
                System.out.println("Deleted : " + messageId);
                queueBean.removeMessage(messageId);
                return;
            }
         }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I use `activemq-all-5.8.0.jar`.